# how to rerender a list when you have changes react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have this component in react native that can select one or multiple images from the gallery or take the image with the cellphone camera, the problem is that it only shows the first time you choose a picture.
i mean if you select 1 image from your gallery and close the selector it is going to show that image, but if you press the button to select pictures again and select another picture, this one isnt showing, but the data is passed, i belive is a trouble with the rerender but dont know how to solve it

this is the component

```
  const MultiImagePicker = ({state, onSubmit}) => {
  const [images, setimages] = useState([]);
  const [items, setitems] = useState([]);
  const [itemModalOpen, setItemModalOpen, toggleModal] = useModal();
  const [Visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.warn('un total de ' + images.length + ' imagenes');
  }, [images]);

  const openImagePicker = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      includeBase64: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: true,
      includeExif: true,
      mediaType: 'photo',
      // maxFiles: 2,
    })
      .then(images => {
        images.map((images, index) => {
          data.append({
            uri: images.data,
            path: images.path,
          });

          setimages(data['_parts']);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => Alert.alert(`Error al cargar imÃ¡genes: ${e}`));
  };

  const openPhotoPicker = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      multiple: false,
      includeBase64: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: true,
    })
      .then((images, index) => {
        data.append({
          uri: images.data,
          path: images.path,
        });

        setimages(data['_parts']);
      })
      .catch(e => Alert.alert(`${e}`));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setitems(images);
  }, [images]);

  const upload = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
    var newArray = [];
    data['_parts'].forEach(element => {
      // const itemJSON = element[0];
      // newArray = newArray.concat(itemJSON);
      newArray = newArray.concat({uri: element[0].uri});
    });

    setVisible(true);
    onSubmit({
      vDocumentB64: newArray,
    });
    toggleModal(true);
  };

  const cleanImages = () => {
    ImagePicker.clean()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('removed all tmp images from tmp directory');
        setimages([]);
        data = new FormData();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data['_parts']));
      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert(e);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    cleanImages();
    if (Visible && state.errorMessage != '') {
      setVisible(!Visible);
    } else {
      setVisible(false);
    }
    return () => {
      isCancelled = true;
    };
  }, [state]);

  if (Visible) {
    return (
      <Spinner
        size="large"
        visible={Visible}
        color="#D32345"
        textContent={'Por favor espera un momento.'}
        textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
      />
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        {images
          ? items.map((item, i) => {
              console.log(item[0].path);
              return (
                <View key={i} style={styles.imagePreview}>
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item[0].path}} />
                </View>
              );
            })
          : null}
      </ScrollView>
      {state.error == true ? (
        <InfoModal
          text={`${
            state.errorMessage !== undefined
              ? state.errorMessage
              : 'Error, las imagenes no pueden estar vacias'
          }`}
          isActive={itemModalOpen}
          handleClose={() => setItemModalOpen(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <InfoModal
          text={`Documento subido exitosamente.`}
          isActive={itemModalOpen}
          handleClose={() => setItemModalOpen(false)}
        />
      )}
      <View style={styles.Buttonscontainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.multiImagePickerButton}
          onPress={() => openPhotoPicker()}>
          <Text style={styles.multiImagePickerButtonText}>Tomar foto</Text>
          <Icon name="camera-alt" color="#fff" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.multiImagePickerButton}
          onPress={() => openImagePicker()}>
          <Text style={styles.multiImagePickerButtonText}>Galería</Text>
          <Icon name="photo-album" color="#fff" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {/* <ScrollView> */}
      {images.length >= 1 ? (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.sendmultiImagePickerButton}
            onPress={() => upload()}>
            <Text style={styles.multiImagePickerButtonText}>
              Cargar y continuar
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.clearmultiImagePickerButton}
            onPress={() => cleanImages()}>
            <Text style={styles.multiImagePickerButtonText}>
              ELIMINAR IMÁGENES
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I saw you are using `data.append` and after looking into your code it seems data is a FormData. Is there any reason to use it like this?

Comment: is your `items` state variable getting updated after reselecting the image ?

Comment: this what i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would be this:
In your upload function you're always concating only the element[0].uri, try concating element.uri

```
data['_parts'].forEach(element => {
      newArray = newArray.concat({uri: element.uri});
    });
```

Also you're calling useEffect twice with the same argument [images], you can do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setitems(images);
    console.warn('un total de ' + images.length + ' imagenes');
  }, [images]);
```

Comment: noo, this didnt work,  the ´data['_parts'].forEach(element => {
      newArray = newArray.concat({uri: element.uri});
    });´ its on the upload function, that function triggers is way after you render the images on the screen

Comment: Have you tried to return item.path instead of item[0].path on you're returning the images?